# Is there a better way to deep copy a UIWebView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, deep-copy

I managed to deep copy a `UIWebView` by loading the `NSURLRequest` in a new `UIWebView`.
I also managed to copy the "scrollTo" position using javascript.
Now I am looking at copying the history and probably many other things.

Is there a documented way to do this properly or am I almost there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there's not straightforward way to implement this.

Since `UIWebView` does not conform to the `NSCopying` protocol, I believe your approach is valid so far.

If you want to make this reusable you may think of subclassing `UIWebView` and implement your copying algorithm inside the `copyWithZone:` method of the `NSCopying` protocol's methods.

If you do so, you can subsequently use the standard `copy` method to deep copy your objects.

As an example

#### UICopyableWebView.h

```
@interface UICopyableWebView : UIWebView <NSCopying>
@end
```

#### UICopyableWebView.m

```
#import "UICopyableWebView.h"

@implementation UICopyableWebView
- (id)copyWithZone:(NSZone *)zone {
     id copy = [[[self class] alloc] init];
    
     if (copy) {
         // copy the relevant features of the current instance to the copy instance
     }
     return copy;
}
@end
```